# Subdomain redirect - Not sure what is happening

Tags: redirect, subdomain

Don't know how this could be solved, so I want your help on this

I already have a subdomain like this: `sub01.example.com`
And all files from that subdomain are stored this tree folder from my server:

```
"example": folder that contains the files from `www.example.com`
 └ "subdomains": folder that only contains other folders
   └ "01", "02", etc.: folder that contains the files from `sub01.example.com`
```

The thing is that when opening `sub01.example.com` from web browser, I stay in that subdomain and even navigate, make form post, etc.
But when opening from mobile browser, and even with incognito session, I always get redirected to `www.example.com/subdomains/01`

What should I do to avoid that redirect? And why this is happening only in mobile?
Not sure if this helps, but all folders tree is set with this permission: `rwxr-x---`

Comment: I would not recommend nesting subdomains inside the main domain directory.   Things usually work better when you use completely separate document roots for different virtual hosts .

Comment: Moved out of the main directory and it worked! Thank you